# How do I specify test timeout for custom NUnit Test Runner?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I run unit tests from code, and my tests can be infinitely long. NUnit keeps running until all tests are closed hence my test session never closes.

```cs
// Get an interface to the engine
Engine.ITestEngine engine = Engine.TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();

// Create a simple test package - one assembly, no special settings
Engine.TestPackage package = new Engine.TestPackage(_testProjectAssemblyPath);

// Get a runner for the test package
var runner = engine.GetRunner(package);

XmlNode testSessionResult = runner.Run(listener: new Listener1(), Engine.TestFilter.Empty);
```

Is it possible to specify a time out without using the `Timeout` [NUnit attribute](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/timeout.html)? Perhaps by specifying `.runsettings`, or using [ISettings](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/Test-Engine-API.html)?

*I tried firing up a task with a timeout, however, this prevents me to see the failing tests, which is mandatory in my use case.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NUnit engine only reads settings from the `TestPackage`. The other approaches you list are used by runners in order to tailor what they add to the `TestPackage`.

To set a general timeout, which applies to all the tests in the run, use something like this...

```
package.AddSetting("DefaultTimeOut", 4000);
```

The above will give each individual test case 4 seconds before it is cancelled.

Setting the timeout for test cases individually is only possible through the attribute.